# jQuery: How to parse through a table using a loop with data from 2 tables when both tables have rows that are the same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a function that appends the information from 2 tables, but both tables have the column "name". How can I dictate which table name is utilized?

```js
function createTableRow(customers) {
  var data = JSON.parse(customers.results);
  if (locations != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var row = $('<tr id=' + data[i].id + '/>');
      $('#table').append(row);
      row.append($('<td>' + data[i].name + '</td>'));
      row.append($('<td>' + data[i].description + '</td>'));
      row.append($('<td>' + data[i].name + '</td>'));
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the database query that is used to make customers.results

```
SELECT customers.name, customers.description, orders.name FROM customers INNER JOIN orders on orders.id = customers.pid
```

Lets say the tables are named **customers** and **orders** both with the column "name"

I want the first **data[i].name** to show the Customers name and the second **data[i].name** to show the Orders name.

Comment: Can you provide us with `customers.results` value so we can better understand your data structure?

Comment: Note on appending: append the row to your table at the end (after putting content into the row element). This will save DOM modifications, repaints and give better performances on the long run.

Comment: @ShaiKatz I've added the query call, hope that helps.

Comment: I want to see what `data[i]` looks like. Can you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data[i]))` and post the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give one of your columns a alias in your SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    customers.name AS cus_name,
    customers.description,
    orders.name 
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders on orders.id = customers.pid
```

Note that `AS` is not required but will make your query a bit more explicit

Then access the customer name with `data[i].cus_name`

Comment: @T.C. You are welcome, then set your question as resolved by ticking the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make alias for `order.name` like

```
SELECT customers.name, customers.description, orders.name as order_name  
FROM customers INNER JOIN orders on orders.id = customers.pid
```

And use `order_name` for showing order name like,

```
row.append($('<td>' + data[i].name + '</td>'));
row.append($('<td>' + data[i].description + '</td>'));
row.append($('<td>' + data[i].order_name + '</td>'));
```